# Can use pipe without fork?

Tags: c, linux, posix, fork

Can I use pipe between two process without using fork and share file descriptors with for example socket ? I don't need another solution, I need pipe between two process that not forked.

Comment: @pst A unix socket is accessed completely different: `connect()`, `accept()` etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a named pipe (FIFO):

if you do `mkfifo <common path>`, you an use this path in both processes, one for reading and one for writing. Then you have the same behaviour as with a normal pipe.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest solution is to use a named pipe, which is a pipe that has a name in the filesystem so that both processes can reference it.  A named pipe is created with the `mkfifo()` call, and opened with `open()` (one process should open it for reading, and the other for writing).

You *can* use an anonymous pipe with two unrelated processes too, but to do so you need to somehow pass an open file description from the process that created the pipe to the other process.  You can do this by using a `SCM_RIGHTS` message on a UNIX domain socket, but if you have a UNIX domain socket then you could just use that to communicate instead of the pipe.  A Linux-specific method is for the second process to use `open()` on the `/proc/<pid>/fd/<fd>` symlink representing the end of the pipe in the first process, but this is quite baroque.